# Making variable updates itself when its previous variable assignment changes

Tags: lua, point

Let's say I have the following code:

```
local a = "first text"
local b = a
print(a) -- prints "first text"
print(b) --  prints "first text"



local c = "second text"
a = c
print(a) --  prints "second text"
print(b) --  prints "first text"
```

So, if I assign variable "a" to be variable "c", the variable "b" is not updated.

I need to make the variable "b" updates itself when I update "a". (in this case, making "b" also have the value of variable "c").

Is there any way to do that?

UPDATE: The code above is just a simplification. On my real scenario, the variables are tables (not strings).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your goal is NOT just "updating a variable". Could you describe what results you need from your program - there might be a better way.

Comment: Hi Oleg. Yes, you are right. The code example above is just a simplification to make the question easier to understood.  On my code a have a table variable DD that is pointing to another table variable EE. I then assign EE to be FF (which is a table as well).  My table DD keeps pointing to the former EE memory slot. I was wondering if Lua would provide a way to make DD "updates itself". My guess is that it does not, but who knows...

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood how variable assignment and data types work in Lua.

Just tables & userdata are stored as references, everything else as values (including strings). `a` gets copied and stored as `b`, `c` gets copied and stored as `a`.

You can put your string in a table as entry, so the table is a wrapper and serves as C pointer.

You can go further in OO-like programming with [metatables](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.4).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Youka, but I don't know if you understood what I really want. The example above is a simplification of what I need. I have A pointing to B, then I make B pointing to C, I want A to point to C automatically (and keep pointing to B). I know that variables that stores non-tables are not references, but even using table variables does not work (that was the first thing that I tried). I also already read metatables and it does not apply. But thanks anyway.